# English minimal pair for /uː/ and /ʊ/ in which /uː/ is rendered as [u]?

Tags: phonemes

There are several English minimal pairs for the phonemes /ʊ/ and /uː/ in which the latter is pronounced [uː], not [u], according to 'common' pronunciation. For example, 'soot', /sʊt/ and 'suit', /suːt/.

However, I didn't manage to find a single minimal pair for these two phonemes in which /uː/ is commonly rendered [u], i.e. unstressed or  clearly short [u].

EDIT:
I hope I don't need to explain what a minimal pair is. The aim of this post is to discover a *minimal pair for the English phonemes /ʊ/ and /u/=/uː/* which is of the particular kind specified above.

I'm not misusing characters at all. /…/ is for phonemes, […] is for phones aka speech sounds.

(And please, don't be condescending.)

Comment: Your question is confusing; see those matters raised in the answer provided. Regarding your first question, are you aware of [these charts showing different choices of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Conventions_for_English)? Regarding your second question, are you aware of [the phenomenon of vowel reduction in unstressed syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English)?

Comment: What dialect of English are you interested in? And what transcription scheme? Standard UK English isn't normally transcribed with /u/ but it seems to be used by some people in some circumstances. And realisation of pretty much every sound written "u" varies a lot. See e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)

Comment: @Stuart F: Let's abstain from restricting the discourse to any particular flavour of English for now, doing so is prone to blurring the question. Put another way, treat any dialect you like ! Transcription scheme: Take, for example, OALD's way of representing things, see [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/).

Comment: There we find: /ˈmjuː.ʧuəlˠ/ and /ˌmjuː.təˈbɪ.lə.ti/ and /ˈspɜ.kju.lɜɪ̯t/. To be clear, I'm aware that the phoneme /u/ can also be denoted /uː/, there's identity.  /u/ and /ʊ/ are different of course, take /ˈpʊl/ and /ˈpuːl/, or 'soot' and 'suit' as in my header post. Maybe now you understand my question better.

Comment: To be even clearer: My question, while being phonemic in part, is also phonemic. Because it seeks a minimal pair for English /u(ː)/ and /ʊ/ which satisfies  an additional requirement concerning the diversity ℎ English /u/.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the edit! I'm going to rephrase to check that I've understood the question correctly.

The question is about whether there are any minimal pairs between the phoneme /u(ː)/ (as in "goose") and the phoneme /ʊ/ (as in "foot") in unstressed syllables. **I don't know of a strict minimal pair.**

The contrast between these vowels is definitely neutralized in the following context:

- the syllable is fully unstressed (i.e. it occurs in a rhythmic context where a reduced vowel such as /ə/ could occur)
- the vowel is word-final or before another vowel (or in other words, the vowel is not followed by a consonant)

In these contexts, most speakers use a quality closer to the sound of /uː/, but in some forms of English (including some forms of "RP"), the quality can be more similar to /ʊ/. Hence the varying transcription of words like "graduate" etc. with /uː/ or /ʊ/.

Sometimes words like "graduate" are transcribed with a third symbol, /u/. The use of /u/ in English phonemic transcriptions is somewhat problematic and an abuse of notation, as this unstressed vowel is not a third phoneme in contrast with /ʊ/ and /uː/; rather, it may be intended as a simple notational shorthand for 'either the phoneme /ʊ/ or the phoneme /uː/' (which we could call a "diaphonemic" transcription), or possibly as a sign indicating a neutralization of these two phonemes (which we could call an "archiphonemic" transcription).

- In this context, there is never a contrast between /ʊ/ and /uː/ independent of the contrast of rhythm/stress/reduction.
- It should not be possible for the symbols /u/ and /ʊ/ to contrast in transcriptions like this (since the transcription /u/ implicitly includes /ʊ/ as a possible realization).
- Another tricky point is that the use of the symbol "/u/" in this context should not be understood as a phonetic transcription: it doesn't mean that the vowel is necessarily [u], or a phonetically shorter version of the /uː/ sound (the phonetic length of high vowels in English is complicated, non-binary and non-phonemic, see discussion in the next section below).

A blog post by Jack Windsor Lewis, [HappYland Revisited etc](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive2.html#blog011) (2007, January 3) discusses some of these points.

In unstressed syllables before a consonant, or in contexts such as compound words where vowel reduction doesn't always apply, the situation is a little less clear. A reduced value might appear in "speculate"; alternatively, the second syllable might just have a schwa sound. Windsor Lewis mentions "bedroom, costume, granule, vacuum, volume" as words that could potentially undergo 'weakening' to "/-u-/". I'm not sure whether we can say that the contrast is fully neutralized, but I don't think I would find it very noticeable whether a speaker used /uː/ or /ʊ/ in the unstressed syllable of one of the listed words.

However, if we take a compound like "handbook", it would sound odd to my ears if  someone used /uː/ in the second syllable.

#### A side discussion on vowel length and the use of length marks in English phonetic and phonemic transcriptions

I was a bit confused by the use of [uː] and [u] in the initial question; part of the reason why is because it isn't necessarily clear what these mean in the context of English ([sut] with no length marker would be possible as a (broad) phonetic transcription of "suit").

The phoneme often transcribed /uː/ is not always phonetically long in duration, and its length doesn't depend only on the degree of stress. In the context of the word 'suit', /uː/ would probably be relatively short phonetically (for me, roughly [ʉ]) because of the influence of the following voiceless consonant /t/. In the word "food", where it is followed by a voiced consonant phoneme, the vowel /uː/ would be phonetically longer, but would remain the same phoneme. See [The Undesirability of length marks in EFL phonemic transcription (1975)](http://www.yek.me.uk/undesire.html) (Jack Windsor Lewis).

Comment: The question is asking about [ʊ] and [uː], where the latter is *spelled* as "u"; the asker is misusing square brackets.

Comment: Oh wait, you may be right. I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: "speculate" in General American English?

Comment: OK, I'll take my time to digest your material. I annotate right away that OALD entries make extensive use of 'u' and 'u:', in stressed and unstressed syllables alike. The purpose of ':' is not phonemic, but to offer duration hints in cases where there is (or should be ?) intraword duration variance. (As for me, this representation has always conveyed a pretty good idea of how to pronounce things.)